# Opening files from Finder with a Qt-based application?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, finder

Apparently, for Cocoa applications, you're supposed to implement `[[NSApp delegate] application:openFile:]` or something like that to allow your application to open files double clicked in Finder.

How do you achieve this functionality using Qt, as the name of the file to be opened is not passed on the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QFileOpenEvent ([Qt4](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfileopenevent.html)/[Qt5](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfileopenevent.html)) should do the trick.

Also see https://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/qq18-macfeatures.html